# how to Center TextBlock totally Auto in a ListBox and Autoresize font text

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

Hi need to center 6 textblock in a listbox in xaml for windows phone. i wrote this code

```
    <!--ContentPanel - inserire ulteriore contenuto qui-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ListBox x:Name="CountryListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="6,6,0,151" Width="444">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Height="Auto" Width="500" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Word}" SizeChanged="TextBox_SizeChanged" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red" FontSize="64"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Parola1}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Height="70"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Parola3}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Height="70"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Parola4}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Height="70"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Parola5}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Height="70"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Parola2}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Height="70"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Button Content="Giusto" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,462,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="button1_Click" />
        <Button Content="Sbagliato" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="251,462,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" />
    </Grid>
```

But i wanna do this with Auto width and height. Any suggestions? 
I have another little question.. how can i auto font resize a textblock without using another object? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want Auto height and width, just set `Height="Auto"` and `Width="Auto"`. I didn't get what you are expecting. Its better to show the screenshots of what is happening, and what you are expecting.

Additionally, if you are expecting your textblock to be center aligned, try setting the property `HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"`

EDIT based on comment:
When you set the `TextWrapping="Wrap"`, the text will continue into the next lines. Unfortunately, there is no Font auto resize option in Windows phone. May be you can try using a Converter, like this

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Word}" FontSize={{Binding Path=Word, Converter={StaticResource TexttoFontSizeConverter}}" />
```

And in the converter you can do something like this

```
public class TexttoFontSizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var text = (string)value;
        if (text.Length > 30)
            return 20;
        else
            return 30; //20 ad 30 are the font sizes
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Note: I haven't tested this

Comment: I understood.. Thx. But anyidea to autofont the text in the textblock? The textwrapping don't work properly and text continues to the next line. Thanks so much for the help

Comment: I understood.. Thx. But anyidea to autofont the text in the textblock? The textwrapping don't work properly and text continues to the next line. Thanks so much for the help @nKchandra

Comment: WOW! i surf all the internet for this trick! Thanks so much! It's work!